# Rails - Does Build affect how many child records are created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

One Article has_many Images. When creating a new Article, Users can add 2 images max.

In my controller I run "build" for images only twice, but when I submit the form that has 3 image fields, it succeeds. Is there any need to run "build" at all? It seems pointless in this scenario, is there another way to better ensure only 2 images are accepted?

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @article = Article.new

  2.times { @article.images.build }
end
```

Note the "2.times" here.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(place_params)
  @article.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @review.save

      params[:images][:image_file].each do |image_params|
        @image = @article.images.create(image_file: image_params, user: current_user)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: article, url: create_article_path(@article), local: true) do |form| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :title %> 
  <%= form.text_area :title %>
</div>

<%= form.fields_for :images, @image do |image| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= image.label :image_file_1, "Image 1" %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image_file, name: "images[image_file][]", id: :article_images_image_file_1 %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= image.label :image_file_2, "Image 2" %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image_file, name: "images[image_file][]", id: :article_images_image_file_2 %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= image.label :image_file_3, "Image 3" %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image_file, name: "images[image_file][]", id: :article_images_image_file_3 %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**SUCCESS** (But why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short -- Your build statement is prepping the view to have 2 child objects.  But you're manually creating them, so you're rendering the build statement as useless.  You don't have to do it this way, you can declare nested attributes in the model, then whitelist in the controller, then auto-add them in the view.  (see code example below)

Build itself does change how many objects are instantiated, but you're overriding that.

You are also manually saving the images, which you do not have to do.  There's a bit of rails magic that saves all the children for you, if you've built them properly.

## CodeView

### 1 The Model

`app/models/article.rb`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images
  validates :images, length: {maximum: 2}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

2 bits of note here.  Firstly, in your validation, only allow 2 object, if you try to save a third, it will fail.  Secondly, accepting the attribute in the model allows you to create safe params in the controller, thus alleviating your need to manually create. (unless of course, you really want to)

### 2 The View

```
<%= form_with(model: article, url: article_path(@article), local: true) do |form| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :title %> 
  <%= form.text_area :title %>
</div>

<%= form.fields_for :images do |image_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= image_form.label "image_file_#{image_form.index + 1}" %>
    <%= image_form.file_field :image_file %>
    <%= image_form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

The change here is a) I added the user directly to the form b.) because you are accepting attribute in the model and we'll whitelist the attribute in the controller, you don't need to pass an object to the field_for -- `:images` will do just fine.  And because you will say to build it twice in your controller, you'll have 2 image objects in the form.  Additionally, because you wanted a label of Image 1 and Image 2, with fields_for you automatically get access to the index of the object (just like you'd have with any array) by calling `object.index`.

### 3 The Controller - New Action

`app/models/article.rb`

Your action works perfectly well, keep it just as it is.

```
def new
  @article = Article.new

  2.times { @article.images.build }
 end
```

### 4 The Controller - Strong Params

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, images_attributes: [:id, :article_id,:user_id, :image_file])
end
```

Whitelisting your params altogether will save time and it's easier to read than permitting them in each controller, though you CAN do that if you need to, for instance if params are allowed in certain actions but not in others.

### 5 The Controller - Create Action

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This will probably look similar if not identical to the default create action in a scaffold, and this is all you need.  The child image objects will not be created unless the parent can be created, so you don't have to worry about adding them in an if save.

Comment: Thanks for this, great explanation - using accepts_nested_attributes_for gives the ability to just run @article.save and create nested children in the same action. My only concern with this method is the potential security issue with using a hidden_field for user_id. Is there any way to use this method, but set the user to current_user in the controller action?

Comment: there's no reason you can't.  You can do that a couple ways that can be found described all over SO. In short,  you could do current_user.article.new(article_params) - or you could even merge the current user in to the strong params.